# @PostMapping vs @DeleteMapping "Required String parameter 'name' is not present"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using REST client for testing. I use exact same query, just changing method from `POST` to `DELETE`. I have same method in Spring Boot 2.0.1 - just changing annotation from `@PostMapping` to `@DeleteMapping`.

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/receiver")
public ResponseEntity<Response> doOperation(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As soon as I change to `DELETE` I am getting error:

```
"Required String parameter 'name' is not present"
```

I have tested it with @PutMapping - works as well.

I am doing something wrong??

**UPDATE 1**

DELETE request:

```
DELETE /api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=e6b750be296f28174196817f126b367a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: somehost:9443
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1.7 (Macintosh; OS X/10.13.4) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 10

name=ASDEF
```

response is mentioned error

POST request:

```
POST /api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something HTTP/1.1
Cookie: PHPSESSID=e6b750be296f28174196817f126b367a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: somehost:9443
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1.7 (Macintosh; OS X/10.13.4) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 10

name=ASDEF
```

Response is 200

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to reproduce it in really simple setup using original spring example gs-rest-service. I have forked it on github [HERE](https://github.com/Lapkritinis/gs-rest-service) It's interesting that MockMvc test passes, but it doesn't work in reality.

I will fill a bug with Spring boot

Comment: export the request as a curl and post it here if you could

Comment: not in curl, but I posted requests

Comment: I think the embedded tomcat is not reading the request body of the delete Request. it seems logical because a DELETE operation should happen only on back of an URI.

Comment: Try hacking the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to create a connector with `setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE")`;

Comment: but that's just bad design. Anyways let me add this as an answer.

Comment: @lapkritinis Are you deleting with request body? As far as I know restTemplate does not support request body, have you tried invoking your url with /api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something&name=asdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not send payload with DELETE requests. DELETE request is like rm command where you ask server to remove the resource.

Sending a payload is undefined and may differ from server to server

From RFC:

```
A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
implementations to reject the request.
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with `Spring` but the embedded `tomcat` itself as the body of `DELETE` requests are usually ignored.

Here is a way around it.

For `spring-boot` 2.0+,

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer
{

    @Override
    public void customize(Connector connector) {
        connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
    }
}
```

same can be done in `spring-boot` 1.5+ as shown below.

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    };
}
```

But this is a bad practice. Because you ended up performing a `POST` but calling it a `DELETE` api.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like you are using `@RequestBody` for your `@PostMapping` but on your `@DeleteMapping` you are using `@RequestParam`.

Also you are invoking your DELETE api with request body instead of a url parameter. From your request info, I see:

```
DELETE /api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something HTTP/1.1
```

But you have to invoke your delete API like this:

```
DELETE /api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something&name=something
                              Here ---------^^^^^
```

With curl you can use:

```
curl -X DELETE '{{url}}/api/v1/wud/receiver?action=something&name=something'
```

On the other hand, if `name` param is not mandatory, then you can use:

```
@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name
```